# How can I do a range query on an array in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents in ElasticSearch that look like this:

```
{"foo": "bar", "params": [ 123, 456] }
```

How can I search for documents that have the first element of params between 100 and 200? Normally I would just use "range" but I don't know how to refer to the first index of params when specifying the query.